# Another process has updated the 'BAccount' record. Your changes will be lost for Payroll/EPEmployees

Tags: c#, acumatica

I have created a  `PXGraphExtension` for the `EmployeeMaint` screen.

Within the `RowInserting` event for `EPPositionHistory`, I need to perform an update on the associated `PayrollEmployee`.

Event handler:

```
 SelectFrom<PREmployee>.Where<PREmployee.bAccountID.IsEqual<EPEmployee.bAccountID.FromCurrent>>.View PayrollEmployee;


        public SelectFrom<MHPRACAEligibility>
              .Where<MHPRACAEligibility.bAccountID.IsEqual<EPEmployee.bAccountID.FromCurrent>.And<MHPRACAEligibility.isCurrent.IsEqual<True>>>
             .View ACAHistory;

        public static bool IsActive()
        {
            return PXAccess.FeatureInstalled<PX.Objects.CS.FeaturesSet.payrollModule>();
        }
        protected virtual void EPEmployeePosition_RowInserting(PXCache sender, PXRowInsertingEventArgs e)
        {
            EPEmployeePosition row = e.Row as EPEmployeePosition;
            if (row != null)
            {

                if (Base.IsImport)
                {

                

                    EPEmployeePosition ep = SelectFrom<EPEmployeePosition>
                           .Where<EPEmployeePosition.employeeID.IsEqual<@P.AsInt>>
                           .OrderBy<EPEmployeePosition.startDate.Desc>
                           .View.SelectWindowed(Base, 0, 1, row.EmployeeID);


                    if (ep != null)
                    {
                        var cacheCopy = Base.Employee.Current;
                   //     Base.Employee.Cache.Clear();
                        this.updateACABenData(ep, row);
                        ep.StartDate = DateTime.MinValue;
                        Base.EmployeePositions.Cache.Delete(ep);
                    }

                }


And the 
            }

        }
```

Code for updating Payroll record:

```
        private void updateACABenData(EPEmployeePosition oldRec, EPEmployeePosition newRec)
        {

            var prEmp = PayrollEmployee.SelectSingle();
            if (!oldRec.IsTerminated.GetValueOrDefault() || !oldRec.EndDate.HasValue || !newRec.StartDate.HasValue || prEmp == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            var oldEnd = oldRec.EndDate.GetValueOrDefault();
            var newStart = newRec.StartDate.GetValueOrDefault();


            // Employee has not been gone long enough to count as a "new" employee. No update needed.
            if (oldEnd.AddDays(BREAK_SERVICE_WEEKS * 7) > newStart)
            {
                return;
            }
            else
            {

                var employeeSettingsGraph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<PREmployeePayrollSettingsMaint>();
                employeeSettingsGraph.PayrollEmployee.Current = prEmp;
                var acaRec = this.ACAHistory.SelectSingle();

                var empExt = prEmp.GetExtension<PREmployeeExtension>();
                empExt.UsrInitMeasureStart = newStart;
                empExt.UsrInitMeasureCalcd = false;
                if (acaRec != null)
                {
                    acaRec.IsCurrent = false;
                    this.ACAHistory.Update(acaRec);
                }


                employeeSettingsGraph.PayrollEmployee.Update(prEmp);
                employeeSettingsGraph.Persist();
            }

        }
```

However, I am receiving an error when the system attempts to persist the record:
     `"exceptionMessage": "Error: Another process has updated the 'BAccount' record. Your changes will be lost.",`

I understand `BAccount` underlies both `PayrollEmployee` and `EPEmployee` and that is the root cause of the issue. However, I am not sure how to work around this. I am obviously not touching any of the BAccount fields when I update the `PayrollEmployee` so conflict should not be a concern (obviously the system does not know that).

Is there an accepted way to the Cache or other methods for handling this scenario? It is possible some of the fields of the EPEmployee may have been updated, so I cannot simply clear the Cache entirely.

Full error:

```
{
    "message": "An error has occurred.",
    "exceptionMessage": "Operation failed",
    "exceptionType": "PX.Data.PXInvalidOperationException",
    "stackTrace": "   at PX.Api.ContractBased.EntityService.Put(ISystemContract systemContract, String version, String name, EntityImpl entity, CbOperationContext operationContext, Boolean throwOnError)\r\n   at PX.Api.ContractBased.Soap.SoapFacadeBase.PutImpl(EntityImpl entity, Boolean throwOnValidationError)\r\n   at PX.Api.ContractBased.SystemContracts.V2.RestController.PutEntity(EntityImpl entity, String select, String filter, String expand, String custom)\r\n   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass6_2.<GetExecutor>b__2(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__6.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__6.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__6.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__6.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.<ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore>d__3.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__6.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__6.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__15.MoveNext()",
    "innerException": {
        "message": "An error has occurred.",
        "exceptionMessage": "Error: Another process has updated the 'BAccount' record. Your changes will be lost.",
        "exceptionType": "PX.Data.PXLockViolationException",
        "stackTrace": "   at PX.Data.PXTableAttribute.PersistUpdated(PXCache sender, Object row)\r\n   at PX.Data.PXCache`1.PersistUpdated(Object row, Boolean bypassInterceptor)\r\n   at PX.Data.PXCache`1.Persist(PXDBOperation operation)\r\n   at PX.Data.PXGraph.Persist(Type cacheType, PXDBOperation operation)\r\n   at PX.Data.PXGraph.Persist()\r\n   at PX.Objects.EP.EmployeeMaint.Persist()\r\n   at PX.Data.PXSave`1.<Handler>d__2.MoveNext()\r\n   at PX.Data.PXAction`1.<Press>d__33.MoveNext()\r\n   at PX.Data.PXAction`1.<Press>d__33.MoveNext()\r\n   at PX.Api.SyImportProcessor.SyStep.PressButton(PXAction button, PXAdapter adapter, SyView view, String actionName, Object[] currents)\r\n   at PX.Api.SyImportProcessor.SyStep.CommitChangesInt(Object itemToBypass, PXFilterRow[] targetConditions, PXFilterRow[] filtersForAction, SyImportRowResult importResult)\r\n   at PX.Api.SyImportProcessor.SyStep.CommitChanges(Object& itemToBypass, PXFilterRow[] targetConditions, PXFilterRow[] filtersForAction)\r\n   at PX.Api.SyImportProcessor.ExportTableHelper.ExportTable()"
    }
}
```

Thanks Much!

Comment: Try commenting out the employeeSettingsGraph.Persist(); and see if the error goes away.  You won't get the save, but I suspect that's the problem.  I normally do Save.Press() instead of Persist() but should be roughly the same, I think.  Persisting the employee in that graph is likely updating your BAccount for employee, so when your main graph tries to save it conflicts.

Comment: Why are you trying to save in `EPEmployeePosition_RowInserting`? This can cause issues. For example, if the record is inserted and then the user clicks the Cancel button, the second record will be saved but the source record will be canceled.

Comment: Where are you getting the error? here? 
employeeSettingsGraph.Persist(); 
Or in the Screen Persist() method?